# Need advice on how to optimize my Scala tests

Tags: scala, scalatest

I am using ScalaTest for automation.
A typical test logical structure is that the test is doing some checks of the application logic and then cleans up. So let's call it a test body part and a test cleanup part. If the test body fails I would like to see it in the test report. If the test body does not fail but the cleanup part fails I also would like to see in the test report that the test ended up with error.
So I've come up with the following structure (example is the most simple I can provide):

```
"Admin" should "be able to create a new team" in{
    val tempTeam = Team("Temp QA Team")
    val attempt=Try{
      When("Admin opens the Teams view")
      TeamsPage.open
      And("creates a new team")
      TeamsPage.createNewTeam(tempTeam)
      Then("this team is shown in the list")
      TeamsPage.isParticularTeamShownInTeamList(tempTeam.name) shouldBe true
    }
    val cleanUp = Try(TeamsPage.cleanUpTeam(tempTeam))
    attempt match{
      case Failure(e) => throw e
      case Success(r) =>{
        if(cleanUp.isFailure) cleanUp.get
        r
      }
    }
  }
```

Please note here that I need the cleanup part to always execute, not only when the test body part is successful.

It works as I expect but I see two problems:

1. IntelliJ Idea tells me that `cleanUp.get` is useless expression. How to write that part in more correct way? I could rewrite it as `if(cleanUp.isFailure) throw cleanUp.failed.get`, then the IDE would not complain but actually that is a longer way to write the same statement.
2. The last part of this test code which actually compares results of the test body part and cleanup part and decides what to return looks a bit bloated. Probably you can advice me how to make it more concise and clear?

Comment: For #2, might this be an appropriate job for `BeforeAndAfter`?  Put your cleanup code in the `after` method.  That might also ease your burden on #1, because the cleanup code wouldn't be in this method anymore.  I'm not a scalatest expert, though, so I could be off base here.

Comment: @IanMcLaird I cannot put it in `after()` since `after` is executing after every test and things which I need to clean up differ in every test. I already use `BeforeAndAfter` and `BeforeAndAfterAll` for common setups/cleanups. The question here actually has a little to do with ScalaTest. It's a generic pattern, when you have to execute two blocks of code, every of them can fail. If the first one fails you would like to report its failure no matter what is the result of the second one, but if the first one goes ok then you still need to report the failure of the seconds block if it fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand what you're trying to do correctly, the answer is `flatMap` and `map` as laid out in the documentation for [`scala.util.Try`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/util/Try.html)

In your case (taking your code as is), you would want

```
"Admin" should "be able to create a new team" in{
  val tempTeam = Team("Temp QA Team")
  val attempt=Try{
    When("Admin opens the Teams view")
    TeamsPage.open
    And("creates a new team")
    TeamsPage.createNewTeam(tempTeam)
    Then("this team is shown in the list")
    TeamsPage.isParticularTeamShownInTeamList(tempTeam.name) shouldBe true
  }
  val cleanUp = Try(TeamsPage.cleanUpTeam(tempTeam))
  attempt.flatMap(r => cleanup.map(c => r)).get
}
```

This will return the result of `attempt`, unless it fails, in which case it will throws `attempt`'s exception.  It will ignore the successful result of `cleanup` (as your code did), but if `cleanup` throws an exception, you'll throw *that* exception.

N.B.  I didn't actually try this in an IDE, so I can't say if this will address your question #1 about IntelliJ saying that `get` was a useless expression.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Ian. I know `map` and `flatMap` but had apparently not scratched my brain enough to properly combine them in this case. Your line of code is precisely what's needed.